# Fantasy book series with a female protagonist who uses psychic powers to kill some people and torture someone for information

Tags: story-identification, books, psychic

I read a book series a few years back that was amazing but I can’t remember the author or title for the life of me.

It’s a fantasy series based in the past. The first book starts finding a female protagonist with psychic powers who is rescued and taken back to a camp. At the camp, she meets a general who also ends up having powers that she helps him learn to use.

There’s a battle at the camp, where she uses her psychic powers to kill a bunch of people and torture someone for information at a different time.

Any help you all have would be amazing thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You mentioned that the series was based in the past; roughly how far in the past are we talking about?

Comment: Was this just the beginning of the book or the entire story?

Comment: Is it really "the" past (i.e. our past), or a fantasy world that's partly based on the past (e.g. steampunk being partly based on the Victorian era, the medieval-ish feel of much fantasy work, etc.)